# Missing citations when reciting cited works (authoryear-comp)

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using biblatex with authoryear-comp for my document. It works fine for authoryear, but authoryear-comp misses citations (or part of) when I recite a cited work. Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese,german,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}
%Bib:
\usepackage[    style=authoryear-comp,
            %natbib=true,
            backend=biber,
            maxcitenames=2,
            firstinits=true,
            maxbibnames=9,
            sorting=nyvt,
            dashed=false,
            eprint=false,
            %numbermonth=false,
            clearlang=true,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            url=false ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lab.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
%\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}
    \AtEveryBibitem{
      \clearfield{edition}
      \clearfield{endday}%
      \clearfield{endmonth}
      \clearfield{month}%
      \clearfield{day}
      \clearfield{language}
      \clearfield{editor}}
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}
%\usepackage{chapterbib}
%\newcommand{\scite}{[\cite{#1}]};

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{citeyear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\defbibheading{secbib}[\bibname]{\section*{#1}}
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{\section*{#1}}

\begin{document}

Multiple works~(\cite{Jaynes1957a,Jaynes1957b,Jaynes1988a})

Reciting:~(\cite{Jaynes1957a})

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

with the bib file

```
@article{Jaynes1957a,
Author = {Jaynes, E T},
Date-Added = {2014-11-13 15:17:17 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-11-13 15:17:17 +0000},
Journal = {Phys. Rev.},
Keywords = {information; probability; statistical-mechanics},
Number = {4},
Pages = {620},
Title = {Infomation theory and statistical mechanics {I}},
Volume = {106},
Year = {1957}}

@article{Jaynes1957b,
Author = {Jaynes, E T},
Date-Added = {2014-11-13 15:17:17 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-11-13 15:17:17 +0000},
Journal = {Phys. Rev.},
Keywords = {information; probability; statistical-mechanics;},
Pages = {171},
Title = {Information theory and statistical mechanics {II}},
Volume = {108},
Year = {1957}}

@incollection{Jaynes1988a,
Author = {Jaynes, E T},
Booktitle = {Maximum Entropy and Baysian Methods in Science and Engineering},
Date-Added = {2014-11-13 15:17:17 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2014-11-13 15:17:17 +0000},
Editor = {Erickson, G. J. and Smith C. R.},
Keywords = {information; thermodynamics;},
Publisher = {Kluwer Academic Publishers},
Title = {The evolution of Carnot's principle},
Volume = {1},
Year = {1988}}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output authoryear-comp]

In some other case (my document), things are even worse: nothing appears at the second citation. On the other hand, authoryear works just fine. Can any of you help me with fixing that problem of authoryear-comp? Thank you a lot!

Comment: The problem is with the way you redefined `\cite`. What do you  want to achieve?

Comment: @Guido I was trying to remove the square brackets that wrap the citations ([]).

Comment: PS:...and colour the whole citations in hyperlink colour...

Comment: When I comment out your definition of `\cite` and `\cite*` I do not get square brackets around citations.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was just for colouring the whole citations instead of the year only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the bibmacro `cite` saves the `hash` (unique for each author name) and year of the last used citation in a variable (actually a command). The current definition of `\cite` does not ensure that the values stored in the variable are cleared. The bibmacro to reset these variable is `cite:init`. That macro has to be executed for every cite command, thus a modified definition would be:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
 \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Alternatively, one could use the current definition and add

```
\AtEveryCite{\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
```

[image]